# How to only show first time visitors specific tooltips?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, cookies

I want to give only first time users a "tour" of my website. I want to do with JavaScript. What I mean is that if the user has never seen my website and that it's his/her's first visit, they will get a tutorial on how to use the website. If they visit again or reload the page, they shouldn't see the tooltip. Can this be done with JavaScript Cookies? I found a PHP code, but I want to avoid PHP for now.

```
<?php
// Top of the page, before sending out ANY output to the page.
    $user_is_first_timer = !isset( $_COOKIE["FirstTimer"] );

// Set the cookie so that the message doesn't show again
    setcookie( "FirstTimer", 1, strtotime( '+1 year' ) );
?>




<H1>hi!</h1><br>


<!-- Put this anywhere on your page. -->
<?php if( $user_is_first_timer ): ?>
    Hello there! you're a first time user!.
<?php endif; ?>
```

If it can't be done with JS, can it be done with .htaccess? I also found this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(www\.)?(https?://)?(?!example\.com) [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/welcome.html [r=307,NC]
```

Comment: If the cookie isn't there, do your tooltip stuff. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Cookies, I can't find anything related to my topic online.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely, although I would prefer using `localStorage` to store the "has the user visited before" information, because if you set a cookie then that cookie will be sent to the server with every. Single. Request. Made. To. Your. Server.

So, try this:

```
if( !window.localStorage) {
    // no localStorage (old browser) - either fall back to cookie method,
    // or just do nothing and skip the whole tour thing - if the user
    // can't be bothered to upgrade, why should you bother to accomodate them?
}
else {
    if( !window.localStorage.isReturningVisitor) {
        // do all the tour stuff here
        window.localStorage.isReturningVisitor = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! localstorage! I prefer it much more than Cookies. I didn't know it was possible. I'll test this out right now.

Comment: If you're going to follow the "do nothing" suggestion, I suggest `if(window.localStorage && !window.localStorage.isReturningVisitor) { /* do tour */ }`

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: @DaKoder Why do you need one? If I did, it would just be a literal copy-and-paste of the code in my answer...

Comment: @Kolink I mean, as in creating a sample window using that code.